# How to Access OneDrive folder with this code

Tags: c++, c

i'm trying to save a file directly to OneDrive, i've used "C:\Users\User\Onedrive\", But i need to use %Onedrive% or similar so that the path to it doesn't matter

I've Tried using a lot of things but with no success

```
file = fopen ("%onedrive%\\Products.txt", "a");

        fprintf(file, "test save");

        fclose(file);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/known-folders

Comment: how do i use this